# Android bluetooth scan button

Tags: android, bluetooth

onCreate, I check whether bluetooth is enabled. If not, prompt user to switch it on.

If during initial launch request to enable BT but the user selects no and proceeds to press the scan button, the app will crash. I do see the BT request dialog firing afterwards though.

If during initial launch request to enable BT but the user selects yes, the scan button does nothing though the `else` branch of my button click gets fired.

The button works fine if bluetooth is switched on before opening the app.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();

    if (btAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) { // if BT not enabled, request to turn on BT.
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
       // getPairedDevices();
    }
    mHandler = new Handler();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

private void init() {
    // Get a reference to button
    final Button btnScanNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScanNew);
    //Set the click listener
    btnScanNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { // Scan for new bluetooth devices
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            btAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
    });

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            //Finding devices
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                String s ="";
                for (int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++){
                    if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){
                        //append
                        s = "(Paired)";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                listAdapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+" "+"\n" +device.getAddress());
            }
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                listAdapter.clear(); // clear the list of existing scanned devices
                btnScanNew.setText("Scanning");
                btnScanNew.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                btnScanNew.setEnabled(true);
                btnScanNew.setText("Scan");
            }
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                if(btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

Declared the following to detect request code.

```
private static final int INITIAL_REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 9 ;
private static final int SCAN_BTN_REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 10 ;
```

Edited `onCreate()` & `onActivityResult()`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();

    if (btAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) { // if BT not enabled, request to turn on BT.
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, INITIAL_REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
       // getPairedDevices();
    }
    mHandler = new Handler();
}



 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      switch (requestCode) {
          case INITIAL_REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //finish();
              }
              break;
          case SCAN_BTN_REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { // if request from scan btn and user enabled bluetooth. Start discovery immediately.
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth open successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  // open the discovery
                  btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                  btAdapter.startDiscovery();
              }
              break;
      }
  }
```

Edited button

```
   btnScanNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { // Scan for new bluetooth devices
            if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableIntent, SCAN_BTN_REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT already enabled, scanning now...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                btAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        }
    });
```

**For simplicity sake, I have removed the initial "upon-launch-check".**

logcat when I launch app with BT off and clicked the scan button and select 'yes' to on BT. It does on the phone's BT but does no scanning and upon 2nd click it crashes.

```
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.matamatamata.myfirstapp/com.example.matamatamata.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.matamatamata.myfirstapp.MainActivity$3@373702de
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3732)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3691)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3666)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1459)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.matamatamata.myfirstapp.MainActivity$3@373702de
                                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:822)
                                                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:2025)
                                                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:528)
                                                                                     at com.example.matamatamata.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:187)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6446)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1308)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3718)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3691) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3666) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1459) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

Comment: Are you waiting for your bluetooth to open? I mean you could use ProgressDialog and check every milliseconds so that mBluetoothAdapter.getState() is ENABLED. Also try replacing            `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);` with `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);`

Comment: Also I don't see where you enable your bluetooth use `btAdabter.enable();`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `onActivityResult()` make a dual check to ensure the Bluetooth has already turned on. This will prevent the app from crashing while pressing the scan button.

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      switch (requestCode) {
          case INITIAL_REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //finish();
              } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                CheckBlueToothState();
              }
              break;
          case SCAN_BTN_REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //finish();
              } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                CheckBlueToothState();
              }
              break;
      }
```

The `CheckBlueToothState()` method should look like this,

```
private void CheckBlueToothState(){
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null){
        //Bluetooth NOT supported
       }else{
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
         if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
          //Bluetooth is currently in device discovery process
         }else{
          //Bluetooth is Enabled
          btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
          btAdapter.startDiscovery();
         }
        }else{
         //Bluetooth is NOT Enabled!
         Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
         startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
       }
   }
```

Now update the button onClickListener,

```
btnScanNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { // Scan for new bluetooth devices
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled() && !btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BT already enabled, scanning now...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            btAdapter.startDiscovery();
           }
            else
           {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, SCAN_BTN_REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }
    });
```

Finally, make sure you have added both of the permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

The `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` applications to discover and pair bluetooth devices

Comment: I don't get the idea of checking the status of btAdapter after `if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)`. The status will always be `enabled` since the user selected ok to turn on BT? Anyway. I have tried your suggestion but it's still crashing. Somehow if I enable BT via in-app-prompt, they stop working. If BT was enabled beforehand, everything works fine.

Comment: Please check the updated onActivityResult() code again. If you still face crashing, please post the logcat. By the way, you can skip the CheckBlueToothState(). I put it for an extra checking.

Comment: updated and removed the initial Bluetooth enable prompt check